# How to output 2 or more arrays in a fortran's function?

Tags: matrix, fortran, numerical-computing, matrix-decomposition

I am writing a program which computes the LU decomposition of a matrix, with partial pivoting, and I would like the function to output several (2 or 3) matrices without running the program several times to output each one individually, which is a waste of time since it gets me everything I want in one run. Is there a way of doing this? For example, here is my function using Doolittle's algorithm, for square matrix which don't need pivoting. I want my output to be matrix l and u at once, but I know no means of doing that.

```
function lu_d(aa) result(l)

real, dimension (:,:) :: aa !input matrix
real, dimension (size(aa,1), size(aa,2)) :: a !keeping input variable intact
real, dimension (size(a,1), size(a,2)) :: l , u !lower and upper matrices
integer :: i,j,k !index
real :: s !auxiliar variable

a=aa

do j=1 , size(a,2)
  u(1,j)=a(1,j)
end do

l(1,1)=1

do j=2, size(a,2)
  l(1,j)=0
end do

do i=2, size(a,1)

  l(i,1)=a(i,1)/u(1,1)
  u(i,1)=0

  do j=2, i-1

    s=0
    u(i,j)=0

    do k=1, j-1
      s=s+l(i,k)*u(k,j)
    end do

    l(i,j)=(a(i,j)-s)/u(j,j)

  end do

  l(i,i)=1

  do j=i, size(a,2)

    s=0
    l(i,j)=0

    do k=1, i-1
      s=s+l(i,k)*u(k,j)
    end do

    u(i,j)=a(i,j)-s

  end do

end do

end function
```

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran]. Add a specific version where necessary to distinguish. Only a very small number of people follow [tag:fortran95].

Comment: Of course there is a way to do this sort of things, but you should show some effort of yours. How does your code look like? Which problems have you find?

Comment: I look up for some information online, but I haven't found anything about it. I will edit the post, and add my code! Just a moment.

Comment: Oh, by output you mean return as a function result? I can't see any array `m` in your code so I am still not sure what you want exactly, but I think it will be easier with a subroutine instead of the function.

Comment: sorr, matrix u, fixed it. So, is it impossible to have 2 results for one function? Something like a "vector of matrices".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch from using a function to using a subroutine. This way you can output values for multiple arrays in the arguments list. Additionally using the
`INTENT` definition when declaring variables in the subroutine, e.g.:

`REAL,INTENT(IN)::a` declares a and does not allow its values to be altered inside the subroutine/function

`REAL,INTENT(OUT)::b` declares b and disregards any values it has coming into the subroutine/function

`REAL,INTENT(INOUT)::c` this is the case by default, if you don't write anything.

I will assume you need the output to be `l` and `u` (rather than `m`), in which case the structure would look something like the one below. Note that `l` and `m` should either be declared in the main program and their size defined with respect to `aa` (as in the first case shown below) OR declared with an `allocatable` size in the main program, passed to the subroutine without being allocated and allocated within the subroutine (second example). The latter may require you to put the subroutine in a module so that the interfaces are handled properly.

First example:

```
SUBROUTINE lu_d(aa,l,m)
implicit none
real,intent(in):: a(:,:)
real,intent(out):: l(:,:), m(:,:)
integer:: i,j,k
real:: s

<operations>

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE lud_d
```

Second example:

```
SUBROUTINE lu_d(aa,l,m)
implicit none
real,intent(in):: a(:,:)
real,allocatable,intent(out):: l(:,:), m(:,:)
integer:: i,j,k,size_a1,size_a2
real:: s

size_a1=size(aa,1)
size_a2=size(aa,2)
allocate( l(size_a1,size_a2), m(size_a1,size_a2))

<operations>

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE lud_d
```

Comment: Surprisingly I do not do this... But can a function return a structure? If so then it could return a structure with the two arrays, but the subroutine seems easier... Which is probably why I do these things that way.

Comment: That is a fair point, technically you could also output a matrix that holds `l` and `m` with the function approach, but then you would have to separate them afterwards. Declaring the result of the function as e.g. `A(size(aa,1),size(aa,2),2)` and then having `A(:,:,1)=l; A(:,:,2)=m` should do it, but you can see the inconvenience.

Comment: @Holmz You can do that but without anonymous structures and without syntactic sugar for easy unpacking that is very inconvenient in Fortran.

Comment: @ptev note that the RETURN is superfluous and may lead some to thing that it is necessary to have RETURN and STOP everywhere. I would definitely not use the RETURN here.

Comment: Noted - need to no some research about the proper use myself as I have inherited a number of codes which have it.